# Unable to store output in a customized manner in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to parse some urls and store them in a dataframe. My script can do it. However, it doesn't do the way I expect.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base = 'http://opml.radiotime.com/Search.ashx?query=kroq'

linklist = []

r = requests.get(base)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"xml")
for item in soup.select("outline[type='audio'][URL]"):
    find_match = base.split("=")[-1].lower()
    if find_match in item['text'].lower():
        linklist.append(item['URL'])

df = pd.DataFrame(linklist, columns=[find_match])
print(df)
```

Current output:

```
0      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s35105
1      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s26581
2  http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t122458...
3  http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t132149...
4  http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t131867...
5  http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t120569...
6  http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t125126...
7  http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t131068...
8  http://cdn-cms.tunein.com/service/Audio/nostre...
9  http://cdn-cms.tunein.com/service/Audio/notcom...
```

Expected output (I wish to kick out the indices as well if possible):

```
0      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s35105
1      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s26581
2      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t122458
3      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t132149
4      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t131867
5      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t120569
6      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t125126
7      http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=t131068
8      http://cdn-cms.tunein.com/service/Audio/nostre
9      http://cdn-cms.tunein.com/service/Audio/notcom
```

Answer (score 1):

You can align. To get rid of index drop it when writing to csv

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
df.to_csv(r'Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: If [this is](https://pastebin.com/CjVqQzpN) what you meant then i'm still getting the same output as I was having earlier. Ignored the indices for now.

Comment: print without indices you can do `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: thanks @chitown88 Mind if I add that? Though I see it looses the alignment so I guess padding is required.

Comment: Oh sure, add that! ya it does lose the alignment I noticed. Try to look it up quickly and couldnt find a solution

Comment: I couldn't either :-(

Comment: Sorry @chitown88, the indices are still there when I applied your suggested line within the script.

Comment: I'm not after any csv output, so this line `df.to_csv(r'Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )` is of no use. I tried several times using this line `df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})` to get the expected output but I'm still getting the result like my current output. Thanks.